# Why selected index change on adding data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datatable, datasource

Whenever we add data source to combobox with code below.

```
            comboBoxBusNo.DataSource = busNo.Tables[0];
            comboBoxBusNo.DisplayMember = "BusId";
            comboBoxBusNo.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Why `private void comboBoxBusNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` event is called. How we can stop this to be called at loading.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a list to a ComboBox, the first item is selected by default, which sets the SelectedIndex to 0.  There are no items prior to binding so no item is selected, thus the SelectedIndex is -1 to begin with.  The SelectedIndex changes from -1 to 0 so the SelectedIndexChanged event is raised.

Comment: how to solve this issue, that index change event is not called on load.

Comment: There is no such solution.  If you bind data to the control then the SelectedIndex is going to change and if the SelectedIndex changes then SelectedIndexChanged is going to be raised.  If what you want is to only be notified of changes made by the user then you're handling the wrong event.  SelectionChangeCommitted is only raised when the user makes a change via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This will stop the event from firing on load.

```
comboBoxBusNo.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBoxBusNo_SelectedIndexChanged;

        comboBoxBusNo.DataSource = busNo.Tables[0];
        comboBoxBusNo.DisplayMember = "BusId";
        comboBoxBusNo.ValueMember = "Id";

        comboBoxBusNo.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBoxBusNo_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: what is comboBoxBusNo_SelectedIndexChanged over here is it any variable or function.

Comment: comboBoxBusNo_SelectedIndexChanged is the name of the event handler for your combo box's selected index change event.

  The first line unattaches it and the last line re-attaches it.